# Performances, mysql queries vs php array

Tags: php, mysql, performance, codeigniter, performance-testing

I'm working with codeigniter, now i'm doing a php loop (x100), in each loop i do a mysql query, the result is fine, 1 sec.
But is it the good way to do it ? 
i could make a single mysql query and find the results in an array with some loops, do you think that would be better ?

Thank's

Comment: A single query will almost certainly be faster and more efficient than 100 individual queries

Comment: If there's a way to combine the logic into a single query it probably would be faster because you'd have only one call out to MySQL instead of 100+, but the single query would have to be relatively efficient. It all depends on your situation. If you need help combining this into a single query please add code to your question.

Comment: You should never run queries in loops.

Comment: @jessica: never say never.

Comment: What kind of query are you doing? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @MarcB - if someone has to ask if it's more efficient to run 1 query than 100, then they should never run queries in loops. Never.

Answer (score 0):

no code to give a real answer. but it might be better to do the loop inside the mysql query depending on if results are reusable or multi results can be taken from mysql query